# Android Mediarecorder IllegalStateexception when calling prepare

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am working with custom settings for recorder, for now just trying to use all the HIGH profile settings, But somehow I am getting IllegalStateexception, what am I missing?

[[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrSKz.gif)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html)

```
    mediaRecorder.reset();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(...);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(...);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(...);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(...);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(...);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(...);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(...);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(...);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(...);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(...);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(..., ...);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(...);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(...);
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(...);
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(...);
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(...);
    mediaRecorder.prepare();
    mediaRecorder.start();
```

The crash is on `mediaRecorder.prepare();` and I can tell that mediaRecorder is never released. So any ideas?